# Is it possible for a manifold of the form $\Sigma \times S^1\times I$ to be hyperkahler?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Given a Riemann surface, $\Sigma$, and finite interval interval, $I\in [0,\pi]$, the manifold $\Sigma \times S^1 \times I$ is four dimensional. Can we place hyperkaehler structure on this manifold, which has boundaries?

Comment: There is an immersion of $\Sigma\times S^1\times {\mathbb R}$ into $E^4$, which means that your manifold even has a flat metric. What are the boundary conditions that you want to impose?

Comment: So what you are saying is that since we can immerse $\Sigma\times S^1\times \mathbb{R}$ into $E^4$ (which I understand to be equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^4$), that means the hyperkaehler structure on $E^4$ can be pulled back to $\Sigma \times S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$, am I right? I am not familiar with boundary conditions for immersions, but I think any boundary conditions will do.

Comment: Or do you mean that any 4-manifold which can be immersed in flat space has a flat metric, which therefore means that it admits hyperkaehler structure?

Comment: Right. This construction will fail if you impose the boundary condition that the boundary is totally geodesic.

Comment: Okay, but there are other boundary conditions whereby the construction works, correct? Also, why is it so that any 4-manifold which can be immersed in flat space has a flat metric?

Comment: Take the pull back of the flat metric from the Euclidean space.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I am a little confused at the moment. Let $\Sigma=\mathbb{C}P^1$. Then, from the points above, $\mathbb{C}P^1 \times S^1 \times I$ admits a flat metric. But how can this be true, if $\mathbb{C}P^1$ is a manifold with nonzero curvature?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. Just as an exercise, construct a flat metric on $S^2\times (0,1)$ by embedding this manifold in $E^3$. Similarly, construct a metric of negative curvature on the same manifold.

Comment: @MoisheCohen If $\Sigma \times S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ can be immersed in $E^4$, and is therefore hyperkaehler, then why can't we do the same for $\Sigma \times S^1 \times S^1$, for arbitrary Riemann surface $\Sigma$? As far as I know, $\Sigma \times S^1 \times S^1$ is only hyperkaehler for $\Sigma =S^1\times S^1$.

Comment: There is a big difference between compact and noncompact manifolds. A closed manifold cannot be immersed in the euclidean space of the same dimension.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I hope you don't mind answering another question. What about a compact manifold with boundary such as $D^2 \times S^1 \times S^1$ (where $D^2$ is a disk), can this be given hyperkaehler structure by immersing it in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: You should define a hyperkahler structure on a manifold with boundary, specifically, what, if any, boundary conditions you are imposing. Your compact manifold still admits an immersion in $E^4$.