# Is the manifold $S^1\times S^1 \times D^2$ a hyperkaehler manifold?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $D^2$ be a disk. Is it possible to show that $S^1\times S^1 \times D^2$, is hyperkaehler?

I have learnt from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326152/is-it-possible-for-a-manifold-of-the-form-sigma-times-s1-times-i-to-be-hype) that in order for this to be true, there should be an immersion of $S^1\times S^1 \times D^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$. However, I have not been able to show this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1 \times D^2$ is clearly hyperkahler: the standard flat metric 
$$ g = d\theta_1^2 + d\theta_2^2 + dx^2 + dy^2$$
is an hyperkahler matric.